# Finding c in probability density function

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function

> Suppose that the p.d.f. of a random variable $X$ is as follows: $$ f(x)
>  = \ \begin{cases} 
>         \dfrac{c}{(1−x)^{1/2}} & \text{for } 0 < x < 1 \\[10pt]
>        0 & \text{otherwise}    \end{cases} \ $$
>
> Solution: $ \displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{c}{(1−x)^{1/2}} \, dx=2c=1$, $c=\dfrac{1}{2}$

I don't understand how $c$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ and not $\frac{-1}{2}$ because in integrating it should be $-2c$ and not $2c$. Is this a property of p.d.f?

Comment: Use `\ge` for $\ge$ and `\text` to render $\text{otherwise}$ instead of $otherwise$.

Comment: be careful, you are integrating a positive function if $c$ is positive, over $[0,1]$. so it may well be $-2c$ as well but then $c$ must be negative. The property of density is $\int f(y)\mathrm{d}y =1$.

Comment: So it doesn't matter?

Comment: I guess you know that $d\sqrt{1-x}$ is $(-1/2)dx/\sqrt{1-x}$ and wonder where the minus sign went.  But the end-point calculation $\left. \sqrt{1-x}\right|_0^1$ works out to $0-1 = -1$ which "cancels" the first minus sign.

Comment: oh got it thanks!

Comment: How did you conclude it should be $-2c$? The integral $$ \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}} $$ is the integral of a nonnegative function over a positively oriented interval ($0$ to $1,$ not $1$ to $0$), so it must be positive.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}}
$$

In this integral, note that if $0<x<1$ then $\dfrac 1 {\sqrt{1-x}}$ is positive. And it's $\displaystyle\int_0^1,$ not $\displaystyle \int_1^0.$ Therefore the value of the integral must be positive.

\begin{align}
u & = \sqrt{1-x} \\
u^2 & = 1-x \\
2u\,du & = -dx \\
\text{As } x & \text{ goes from $0$ to $1$, $u$ goes from $1$ to $0$.} \\[10pt]
\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}} & = \int_1^0 \frac{-du}{\sqrt u} = \left. -2\sqrt u \vphantom{\frac 1 1}~\right|_1^0 = -2(0-1) = 2.
\end{align}